# Mail Not Working in vtiger 7.1.0

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I have created a workflow for sending a mail while a new ticket is created. I have configured server my Outgoing Server & while creating a new ticket new entries were inserted in com_vtiger_workflowtask_queue table; but mail were not sent to the desired users. What could be the possible reasons ?

Comment: Please check that you have enabled Vtiger cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the Above Response please create a workflow ; Go to CRM settings > Workflows & then select **Send Email to Contact on Ticket Update** workflow. Make sure you selected trigger point as Ticket updated which includes Ticket creation.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following parameters -

1. Check the permission of the cron/vtigercron.sh file if you are using Linux server.
2. Please check CRON. If you are using Linux server then check the same using 'crontab -e' command.
3. Login as an admin and check the outgoing server configuration 'HOME > Configuration > Outgoing Server'
   [image]
4. Also, check the value 'From Email' parameter in Outgoing Server configuration and admin user email address. Both must be same.

Comment: I completed outgoing server configuration and its working now.Thanks bro.